# Where can i get the GUID value the interface and class for creating DLL, C#

Tags: c#, dll, com, guid

Where can I get the GUID value of the interface and of the class for creating DLL in C#? I use Viusal Studio 2005.Please help.?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Wrapper
{
[Guid("")] => Where can i get this???
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface _Service
{
    [DispId(1)]
    SearchResponse ExecuteSearch();
}

[Guid("")] => Where can i get this???
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("Wrapper.Service")]
public class Ebil : _Service
{
FactService ew;

    public Ebil()
    {
        ew = new FactService();

    }

    public SearchResponse ExecuteSearch(SearchRequest searchRequest)
    {
        return ew.ExecuteSearch(searchRequest);
    }
```

}
}

Comment: You are asking how to generate a guid to place in the attribute contructor, or how to get the guid that was placed in there at runtime? I assume the latter.

Comment: @Juan Ayala - no he needs to get some guids for his classes as arguments for the GuidAttribute, which overrides the automatic type guids.

Answer (score 5):

Use a GUID-Generator of your choice, or [follow this link](http://www.guidgenerator.com/).

---

> [GuidAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx)
>
> Supplies an explicit System.Guid when an automatic GUID is
>   undesirable.

It only has to be compatible with the Constructor of the `Guid` class:

> The string passed to the attribute must be in a format that is an
>   acceptable constructor argument for the type Guid. To avoid conflicts
>   with the type Guid, use the long name GuidAttribute explicitly. Only
>   use an explicit GUID when a type must have a specific GUID. If the
>   attribute is omitted, a GUID is assigned automatically.

Answer (score 4):

The `GUID` property of the `Type` class. Try

```
typeof(_Service).GUID;
typeof(Ebil).GUID;
```